# OpenCL Kernel for String Concatenation

Tags: c, string, algorithm, opencl, gpgpu

I haven't found much literature or examples of performing operations on strings with the GPU.  Specifically, I have 2 arrays of strings and I need to concatenate the elements of the 2nd array to the corresponding elements of the 1st array.  I cannot figure out how to write the kernel for this.

An example of concatenation in C would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void concatenate_string(char*, char*, char*);

int main()
{
   char original[100], add[100], result[100];
   printf("Enter source string\n");
   scanf("%s", original);
   printf("Enter string to concatenate\n");
   scanf("%s", add);
   concatenate_string(original, add, result);

   printf("String after concatenation is \"%s\"\n", result);

   return 0;
}

void concatenate_string(char *original, char *add, char *result)
{
    while(*original)
    {
       *result = *original;
       original++;
       result++;
    }
    while(*add)
    {
       *result = *add;
       add++;
       result++;
    }
    *result = '\0';
}
```

Below is my OpenCL host code containing the kernel.  The kernel follows the same flow as the concatenate_string function above.  The program executes successfully, but gives me no output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif
#include <ocl_macros.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//Common defines 
#define VENDOR_NAME "AMD"
#define DEVICE_TYPE CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
#define VECTOR_SIZE 1024 
using namespace std;

//OpenCL kernel which is run for every work item created.
//The below const char string is compiled by the runtime complier
//when a program object is created with clCreateProgramWithSource 
//and built with clBuildProgram.
const char *concat_kernel =
"__kernel                                       \n"
"void concat_kernel(                            \n"
"                  __global uchar *D,           \n"
"                  __global uchar *E,           \n"
"                  __global uchar *F)           \n"
"{                                              \n"
"    //Get the index of the work-item           \n"
"    int index = get_global_id(0);              \n"
"    while(D[index])                            \n"
"    {                                          \n"
"        *F[index] = *D[index];                 \n"
"        D[index]++;                            \n"
"        F[index]++;                            \n"
"    }                                          \n"
"    while(E[index])                            \n"
"    {                                          \n"
"        *F[index] = *E[index];                 \n"
"        E[index]++;                            \n"
"        F[index]++;                            \n"
"    }                                          \n"
"    *F[index] = '\0';                          \n"
"}                                              \n";

int main(void) {

    cl_int clStatus; //Keeps track of the error values returned. 

    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id * platforms = NULL;

    // Set up the Platform. Take a look at the MACROs used in this file. 
    // These are defined in common/ocl_macros.h
    OCL_CREATE_PLATFORMS( platforms );

    // Get the devices list and choose the type of device you want to run on
    cl_device_id *device_list = NULL;
    OCL_CREATE_DEVICE( platforms[0], DEVICE_TYPE, device_list);

    // Create OpenCL context for devices in device_list
    cl_context context;
    cl_context_properties props[3] =
    {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
        (cl_context_properties)platforms[0],
        0
    };
    // An OpenCL context can be associated to multiple devices, either CPU or GPU
    // based on the value of DEVICE_TYPE defined above.
    context = clCreateContext( NULL, num_devices, device_list, NULL, NULL, &clStatus);
    LOG_OCL_ERROR(clStatus, "clCreateContext Failed..." );

    // Create a command queue for the first device in device_list
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_list[0], 0, &clStatus);
    LOG_OCL_ERROR(clStatus, "clCreateCommandQueue Failed..." );

    // Allocate space for vectors D, E, and F 
    string *D = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string)*VECTOR_SIZE);
    string *E = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string)*VECTOR_SIZE);
    string *F = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string)*VECTOR_SIZE);
    for(int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        D[i] = ".25_numstring";
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        E[i] = "string_2";
        F[i] = "0";
    }
    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector
    cl_mem D_clmem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
            VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(string), NULL, &clStatus);
    cl_mem E_clmem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
            VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(string), NULL, &clStatus);
    cl_mem F_clmem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
            VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(string), NULL, &clStatus);

    // Copy the Buffer D and E to the device. We do a blocking write to the device buffer.
    clStatus = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, D_clmem, CL_TRUE, 0,
            VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(string), D, 0, NULL, NULL);
    LOG_OCL_ERROR(clStatus, "clEnqueueWriteBuffer Failed..." );
    clStatus = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, E_clmem, CL_TRUE, 0,
            VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(string), E, 0, NULL, NULL);
    LOG_OCL_ERROR(clStatus, "clEnqueueWriteBuffer Failed..." );

    // Create a program from the kernel source
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
            (const char **)&concat_kernel, NULL, &clStatus);
    LOG_OCL_ERROR(clStatus, "clCreateProgramWithSource Failed..." );

    // Build the program
    clStatus = clBuildProgram(program, 1, device_list, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(clStatus != CL_SUCCESS)
        LOG_OCL_COMPILER_ERROR(program, device_list[0]);

    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "concat_kernel", &clStatus);

    // Set the arguments of the kernel. Take a look at the kernel definition in concat_kernel 
    // variable. First parameter is a constant and the other three are buffers.
    clStatus |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&D_clmem);
    clStatus |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&E_clmem);
    clStatus |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&F_clmem);
    LOG_OCL_ERROR(clStatus, "clSetKernelArg Failed..." );

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t global_size = VECTOR_SIZE; // Process one vector element in each work item
    size_t local_size = 64;           // Process in work groups of size 64.
    cl_event concat_event;
    clStatus = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
            &global_size, &local_size, 0, NULL, &concat_event);
    LOG_OCL_ERROR(clStatus, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel Failed..." );

    // Read the memory buffer F_clmem on the device to the host allocated buffer C
    // This task is invoked only after the completion of the event concat_event
    clStatus = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, F_clmem, CL_TRUE, 0,
            VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(string), F, 1, &concat_event, NULL);
    LOG_OCL_ERROR(clStatus, "clEnqueueReadBuffer Failed..." );

    // Clean up and wait for all the comands to complete.
    clStatus = clFinish(command_queue);

    // Display the result to the screen
    for(int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%s + %s = %s\n", D[i].c_str(), E[i].c_str(), F[i].c_str());

    // Finally release all OpenCL objects and release the host buffers.
    clStatus = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clStatus = clReleaseProgram(program);
    clStatus = clReleaseMemObject(D_clmem);
    clStatus = clReleaseMemObject(E_clmem);
    clStatus = clReleaseMemObject(F_clmem);
    clStatus = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    clStatus = clReleaseContext(context);
    free(D);
    free(E);
    free(F);
    free(platforms);
    free(device_list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, there's a reason why there's not much literature on GPU-accelerated string operations: there's typically very little computation involved and so moving it to the GPU isn't a win.  It might be a wash if you're on a UMA system since you can avoid the bus transfer, but you'll still probably be IO-bound.

Comment: @MooseBoys, I think you might be right, I just wanted to get some benchmarks.  I have several thousand files that are tens of thousands of lines long each, and I need to perform this concatenation operation on them, so I was curious to see any speed improvements.

Comment: In that case you're definitely going to be file-IO-bound.  Even at peak throughput, SATA 6Gbps doesn't come close to system memory bandwidth, your next bottleneck on a UMA system.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will see much of a gain by offloading the concat operation to a GPU, but here is how I would do it:

```
__kernel void concat_kernel(__global uchar *D,__global uchar *E,__global uchar *F, const int dSize, const int eSize)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    int globalSize = get_global_size(0);

    int i;
    for(i=gid; i< dSize; i+= globalSize){
        F[i] = D[i];
    }

    for(i=gid; i< eSize; i+= globalSize){
        F[i+dSize] = E[i];
    }

    if(gid == globalSize-1){
        //using the last work item here because it will be
        //idle when (dSize+eSize) % globalSize != 0
        F[dSize + eSize -1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

You need to pass in the sizes of the strings you want to concatenate, instead of searching for the null value. This kernel will work with any number of work items, and with different-sized D and E inputs. As usual, F needs to be large enough to hold dSize+eSise+1 chars.

Each work item will copy about (dSize+eSize)/globalSize chars to the output.

Room for improvement:

- try different global work sizes to find the optimal value for your device and input size
- the global memory access should be pretty good, if you want to try a single work group and use local memory, this could help, but you will be bound by the global read speed.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, have you already run this kernel?  If you look at my host code, can you see any problems with the way I have created my strings or allocated memory?  I've suspected I'm passing my strings incorrectly to the kernel, but I'm not getting any run-time errors, other than the complete absence of output.

Comment: if you have any other resources concerning text operations on the GPU, I would be curious to read it.  I'm just now coming to understand that it would be of little gain.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your host code. Have you had success with other kernels in the past? There are some good reduction kernels that show how to structure the host code well.